# Javascript: reconnect to socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I`m trying to make a script, if the socket.io server (on port 3872) is down, the type is "undefined" and when its connected "object". This works. But how to reconnect with socket.io?

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3872');

$(document).ready(function() {
    var p = 0;
    var tryToConnect = 1;
    var connected = false;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(typeof(socket) == "undefined") {
            if(p < 3) {
                $( "#waiting" ).append(".");
                p++;
            } else {
                p = 0;
                $( "#waiting" ).html("Verbinden met de chatserver");
            }
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3872');
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    }, 500);
});
```

But now, it only try to connect at the first line, but in the loop it does not. How to (force) reconnect socket.io?

Comment: Your `socket` is going to go out of scope as it's defined within the anonymous function of your `setInterval`. So each interval, the socket will always be `undefined`.

Comment: Well, yes. But how then reconnect to socket.io?

Comment: I don't think your reconnecting. Each interval you are creating a new connection. You need to get your scoping right for this to have a chance of working as you expect it to.

Comment: And, how do you change the scope? Editing socket.io?

Comment: [Scoping](http://dailyjs.com/2012/07/23/js101-scope/) deals with how/where you define your functions and when they are accessible. In this case you create your `var socket` inside of a function - as a result the variable is not available once the function completes. Try it: before your last `});` do an `alert(socket);`. You'll find it is `undefined`. In short, declare your socket outside of your anonymous function.